# Concept of set without concept of member?

Tags: set-theory

Are there any theory of objects, close to set theory, but where definition does not include the concept of set member and the concept of belongness?

Only such operations as intersection, union and so on?

This theory can be build like vector space theory. For example, empty set can be defined as object, which gives itself if intersecting with any other object.

And so on.

Is it possible to build interesting and apparently complete theory this way?

Comment: What do you mean by complete theory ?

Comment: What about a category-theoretic formulation of set theory, like ETCS? Since it's not a material set theory, it doesn't have set membership as an absolute notion. On the other hand, it introduces additional primitive notions, namely morphisms and a natural numbers object, to yield a theory almost as powerful (in particular, equivalent to bounded Zermelo + Choice, if I recall correctly), so it might not be the sort of thing you're looking for.

Answer (score 5):

There are several theories that capture part of the structure of sets without using elements.  If you just want the operations of intersection and union, you could work with lattices, or, to capture more of the properties of those set-theoretic operations, distributive lattices.  If you also want to talk about complements, then Boolean algebras become relevant.  There are lots of variations, depending on what operations you want to include and which properties of those operations you want to assume.  For example, there are lots of lattice-theoretic axioms weaker than distributivity. And Heyting algebras are like Boolean algebras except they have only those properties of set-theoretic operations that are constructively valid.  (Although I've listed several options, they are only the tip of the iceberg; I hope it's a big enough tip to be useful.)

Comment: If consider a lattice, then join stands for intersection and meet stands for union, right? Then what stands for empty set? How to guarantee that $A \cup \emptyset = A$ and $A \cap \emptyset = \emptyset$? Is this come from lattice definition? And how to model instersection and union of 3 and more sets?

Comment: @Dims It's the other way around; join plays the role of union, and meet plays the role of intersection. Some people (including me) prefer to define "lattice" in a way that requires the presence of a smallest and a largest element. Then the smallest element plays the role of the empty set, and the two equations you asked about follow immediately from the definition. The join of 3 sets can be produced by repeated join of 2 sets at a time: $(A\lor B)\lor C$. Similarly for meets, and similarly for more than 3 sets.

Comment: Many people (probably still a majority) disagree with my preference for requiring the existence of top and bottom elements in a lattice. For these people, lattices would model only the intersection and union structure of sets, not the notion of empty set.

Comment: Having smallest and/or largest element is not mandatory for a group, right? Hence, existing for such elements is additional feature.

Comment: "Smallest" and "largest" don't even make sense in the context of a group; groups don't have an ordering as part of their group structure. In the case of ordered groups, the only one with a smallest (or, equivalently, a largest) element is the trivial group.

Answer (score 4):

Intersection and union generally refer to sets. The theory of locales and frames is like topology without points. They use a Heyting Algebra. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complete_Heyting_algebra).

Also you might read about [lattices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lattice#Mathematics).

In these structures the operations are usually referred to as meet and join. If the structure has a least element that element will behave like the empty set.

Answer (score 0):

The keyword you are looking for is *structural* set theory. The opposing notion — focused on membership — is *material* set theory

There fairly are well-developed structural set theories. For example, the *elementary theory of the category of sets* — ETCS for short — is a good set-theoretic universe to do mathematics in.

There are also various approaches via *type theory*, but AFAIK those tend to be more oriented towards the needs of formal logic and computability theory.

---

In both cases, one can devise a suitable formal language so that doing mathematics in a structural set theory still resembles how mathematics looks in a material set theory; one just has a different interpretation of what the symbols mean.

For example, category theory teaches us that the notion of a morphism $U \to X$ is a very good substitute for the notion of an element of $X$, and this works especially well in the type of category described by ETCS, so great swaths of mathematical ideas can be adapted to structural set theory simply by replacing "element of $X$" with "morphism with codomain $X$".

This means one can study structural set theories in a relatively familiar manner, rather than having to give up everything one has learned about mathematics and adopt a new and alien language.

The new and alien language is still *there*, of course, to be used when you're comfortable with it. For example, a lot of category theory can be usefully depicted with diagrams of vertices and arrows, and there even exist formal diagrammatic languages!

Comment: That can't be right, that arrows replace membership. Since we have the identity morphism, this would mean that every set is an element of itself; and using constant functions, every nonempty set is an element of every nonempty set.

Comment: @Asaf: The *notion* is a substitute; $\to$ isn't meant to be a literal drop-in for $\in$. See "generalized element" for more on the topic. The identity morphism on $X$ serves the role of a 'general' element of $X$. The Yoneda lemma gives one precise way to make the correspondence with elements concrete: understanding $X$ is the same thing as understanding $\hom(-, X)$.

Comment: @Asaf: Maybe another way to describe the intuition is that if you have some notion of "element of $U$", then any function $x : U \to X$ should transfer that notion to be that of an "element of $X$". And in the end you find that working with $x$ is all you need; you never need to actually give meaning to "element of $U$". $U$ is thought of as some implicit 'domain of variation' on which everything in a formula is defined; we never need to figure out what such a thing really means, we just need to use functions whose domain comes from $U$.

Comment: @Asaf: An example of the notion in practice is the definition of "monic morphism". The element-wise definition "$\forall x,y \in X: f(x) = f(y) \implies x = y$" in the language of sets becomes the arrow wise definition for arbitrary categories is $\forall U : \forall x,y : U \to X : f \circ x = f \circ y \implies x = y$. With all of the "internal language of a category" machinery in place, the former formula *literally means* the latter.